# How to get a picture or image dynamically , When click on button in WordPress post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I defined the post type
I want to show a picture whenever I click on a button.
I wrote the code I came up with, and I uploaded a photo to get a better idea
Written Typed Post Code
The subject and photo are typed from the post and there is no problem
The problem is just the type of implementation that just clicked on each button to show the corresponding image.
Here is the code I wrote in index.php:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="side-left-btn" onclick="showHide()">
                            <?php

                            // WP_Query arguments
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => array( 'Exhibition' ),
                            );

                            // The Query
                            $exhibition = new WP_Query( $args );

                            // The Loop
                            if ( $exhibition->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $exhibition->have_posts() ) {
                                    $exhibition->the_post();
                                    ?>
                                    <button class="btn btn-inner" id="uik"><?php the_title(); ?></button>

                                    <?php

                                }
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            }
                            ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <?php

                        // WP_Query arguments
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => array( 'Exhibition' ),
                        );

                        // The Query
                        $exhibition = new WP_Query( $args );

                        // The Loop
                        if ( $exhibition->have_posts() ) {
                            while ( $exhibition->have_posts() ) {
                                $exhibition->the_post();

                                ?>
                                <div id='hidden_div' style='display:none;'>

                                 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array(
                                    'class' => 'img-inner',
                                    'id'    => 'imgss',

                                ) );
                                ?>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                            function showHide() {
                                document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
                            }
                        </script>


                                </div>

                                <?php
                            }
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8327097034/8080.PNG

Answer (score 2):

## First change your code to this

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="side-left-btn">
                            <?php

                            // WP_Query arguments
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => array( 'Exhibition' ),
                            );

                            // The Query
                            $exhibition = new WP_Query( $args );

                            // The Loop
                            if ( $exhibition->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $exhibition->have_posts() ) {
                                    $exhibition->the_post();
                                    ?>
                                    <button onclick="showHide(this)" post_id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" class="btn btn-inner" id="uik"><?php the_title(); ?></button>

                                    <?php

                                }
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            }
                            ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">

                                <div id='hidden_div'>
                                </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

## Second add this code in function.php

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(pid){
    var p_id = jQuery(pid).attr('post_id');
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'get_post-image', post_id: p_id },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data != '' || data != null){
            jQuery('#hidden_div').html( data );
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
<?php 
}?>
```

## Add this also in function.php

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_ajax_get_post-image' , 'get_post-image');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post-image','get_post-image');
function get_post-image(){
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full'); 

echo '<img src="'.$featured_img_url.'" />'; 
exit;
}
?>
```

## Explanation

The above code get the image via ajax, on click button

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this code did not work

Comment: share your site url

Comment: site is in localhost